Value cannot be null or empty: Parameter name: linkText. MVC
Below is my table in the View and controller, not sure why it gives an empty error on the last column at the mainId.
This is my table in the view:
    @model IEnumerable<ListViewModel>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark text-white">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Date</th>               
            <th>More detail ...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in @Model)
        {

            <tr class="table-primary">
                <td>@item.tbl_saved.rowid </td>
                <td>@item.tbl_main.user_logged_in</td>
                <td>@item.tbl_saved.date_created</td>                   
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.tbl_main.user_logged_in, "Details", "Home", new {                mainId = item.tbl_main.Id }, null)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Controller for this table:
        var query = from pd in _context.tbl_main
                    join p in _context.tbl_saved on pd.Id equals p.mainId
                    orderby p.rowid
                    select new ListViewModel { tbl_main = pd, tbl_saved = p };
        return View(query);

The table loads fine when I comment this out:
   <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.tbl_main.user_logged_in, "Details", "Home", new {                mainId = item.tbl_main.Id }, null)</td>

But I want this to navigate to the details obviously.

According to your error message you could find, it said the  linkText couldn't be null.
The first parameter for the ActionLink is the Linktext which means the item.tbl_main.user_logged_in is null which caused this issue.

To solve this issue, you have two ways , firstly check the query inside the controller to make sure the tbl_main.user_logged_in is not null.
The second way is write a condition to check the tbl_main.user_logged_in is null or not inside the view, like below:
        @foreach (var item in @Model)
        {

            <tr class="table-primary">
                <td>@item.tbl_saved.rowid </td>
                <td>@item.tbl_main.user_logged_in</td>
                <td>@item.tbl_saved.date_created</td>                   
                <td>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.tbl_main.user_logged_in))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Home", new { mainId = item.tbl_main.Id }, null)
    }
    else
    {
        <text>N/A</text> <!-- or any other placeholder or message -->
    }
</td>
            </tr>
        }


Thank you kindly, this was the first time I saw what linkText is, never came across this error before.
